# Nunjucks console log not working as node js template engine

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

I am new in node js "nunjucks" templating, i have got most of the information available in nunjucks docs but i don't know how to console the variable init ?

i tried following but didn't worked for me:

`{{ console.log(varible) }}`

Answer (score 2):

the following worked fine on the front end for me:

If you want to log "Cabin" as a string you can use

```
<script> console.log( "Cabin" )</script>
```

If you want to log a variable, try:

```
{% set thing=5 %}
<script> console.log({{ thing }})</script>
```

...which returns 5 (the number)

EDIT: As Valorad pointed out below, if the 'thing' you're trying to point out is not a string, you may have to do some processing and add a few filters before the console.log(); outputs the proper info in the console, such as:

```
<script> console.log(JSON.stringfiy({{ thing }}))</script>
```

OR, more likely:

```
<script> console.log('{{ data.page | dump | safe }}')</script>
```

Thanks Valorad for reporting back!

Comment: But what if I do not know what "thing" is? Like when "thing" is an object, it throws an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in console becasue it gets "console.log([object Object])" rendered in DOM.

Comment: It's my understanding that [object Object] is just a string rendering. Have you tried `<script> console.log(JSON.strigfiy({{ thing }}))</script>`?  I feel like i've definitely encountered that in the past, but can't seem to recreate the issue. Keep us posted!

Comment: No, this does not work either, as it outputs plain [object Object] string, not a json object. Well in fact I later found a way to output this: `<script> console.log('{{ data.page| dump | safe }}')</script>`

Comment: Ah, yes. I almost suggested this, but I thought this, but since I couldn't recreate it, I couldn't test it. This worked okay for you? (Nunjucks documentation is not super great, so I end up consulting jinja docs too sometimes). \

Comment: So both of those options do not work for me. If I set `{{w.data}}` it prints `[Object object]` but when I do either the console with `JSON.stringify` or simply with `{{ w.data | dump }}` per the docs (I've tried with `| safe` too) and it throws a template build error. Ironically if I paste in the example from the docs

```
{% set items = ["a", 1, { b : true}] %}
{{ items | dump(2) }}
```
That works. I'm getting very frustrated at this point.

Comment: @gregwhitworth It sounds like w.data is undefined or not being set properly. Since it works when you explicitly set items in the template. I'd focus on whatever code you have delivering data to the template to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    console.log({{ surveyData | dump | safe}})
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using it this way.

`dump(2)` indents the object to be readable.

```
<script>console.log("data:", `{{ data | dump(2) | safe }}`)</script>
```